# Substantial time to push UIViewController in Twitter completion block

Tags: ios, api, twitter

When running this code...

```
-(IBAction)loginWithTwitter:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Logging in with twitter");
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [self showError:error];
        return;
    }

    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
            NSLog(@"Multiple twitter accounts");
        }

        ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount);

        [self pushMainController];
    }
}];
}
```

There is a 5-10 second delay before the `pushMainController`is actually called, even though the account information is logged almost immediately (after pre-authorization). If I move the `pushMainController` call after the block however, it happens immediately, the only problem being that a user isn't necessarily logged in at that point. I understand that it can take a second for a block to have a response due to variables such as network connectivity, but can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block is not being done on the main queue. You need to ensure your UI code gets done on the main thread:

```
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [self showError:error];
        return;
    }

    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
            NSLog(@"Multiple twitter accounts");
        }

        ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self pushMainController];
        });
    }
}];
```

You may have to wrap the `showError` call as well.